# New environment with content inside multicolumn

Tags: tables, environments, multicolumn

I'm trying to create a new environment with arguments that puts the content inside a multicol like this

```
\begin{tabular}{p{5em} p{\textwidth-3\columnsep -5em}}\\[-0.5em]
\toprule \addlinespace[1.4ex]
\textbf{NFR-1} & \textbf{Extensibility} \hfill \textbf{P1} \\ \addlinespace
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth] \addlinespace[1.4ex] 
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-2\columnsep}}{Description text} \\ \addlinespace
\midrule \addlinespace
\end{tabular}\\[1em]
```

which becomes
[image: correct table]

When i setup the new environment as in this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{card}[4]{
\hypertarget{#1:#2}{}
\vspace{0.75ex}
\centering
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{1.2ex}
\begin{tabular}{p{5em} p{\textwidth-3\columnsep -5em}}\\[-0.5em]
\toprule \addlinespace[1.4ex]
\textbf{#1-#2} & \textbf{#3} \hfill \textbf{#4} \\ \addlinespace
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth] \addlinespace[1.4ex] 
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-2\columnsep}}
}{
\\ \addlinespace
\midrule \addlinespace
\end{tabular}\\ [1em]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{card}{NFR}{1}{Extensibility}{P1}
Description text.
\end{card}
\end{document}
```

it looks strange:
[image]

I think it doesnt like the splitup of the multicolumn command.
I've already tried `\bgroup` and `\egroup` but that only produced errors.

What can be done in a situation like this?

Comment: Don't you get an error? Your example doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @cfr, in MWE is missed package `calc`.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, I know. But the OP should test before posting code so that people don't have to spend time figuring out how to make the problem work before they can try to solve it :-).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I just checked if the pdf gets generated and looks ok, i will better check for errors in the future ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: funny tabular]

`environ` provides a way of defining new environments such that you can process the entire contents of the environment, which it captures in a macro. By default, the contents is stored in `\BODY`, although you can customise this if necessary to avoid clashes (see manual, `prooftrees.sty` includes an example of how to do this to avoid clashing with `forest.sty`'s usage of `\BODY`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,environ,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewEnviron{card}[4]{%
  \hypertarget{#1:#2}{}%
  \vspace{0.75ex}%
  \centering
  \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{1.2ex}%
  \begin{tabular}{p{5em} p{\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-5em}}\\[-0.5em]
    \toprule \addlinespace[1.4ex]
    \textbf{#1-#2} & \textbf{#3} \hfill \textbf{#4} \\ \addlinespace
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth] \addlinespace[1.4ex]
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-2\columnsep}}{\BODY} \\ \addlinespace
    \midrule \addlinespace
  \end{tabular}%
  \vspace{1em}% you can't use \\ here and should never use it outside tabular etc. anyhow
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{card}{NFR}{1}{Extensibility}{P1}
  Description text.
\end{card}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you elaborate in answer, where is defined `\BODY`?

Comment: @Zarko You mean just this ^^?

Comment: yes, I mean this. I suspect that `BODY` come from package `environ`  but so far I didn't use it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You want a one column tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{card}[4]{%
  \par\hypertarget{#1:#2}{}\vspace{0.75ex}
  \centering
  \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{1.2ex}
  \begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}\\[-0.5em]
  \toprule
  \addlinespace[1.4ex]
  \makebox[5em][l]{\textbf{#1-#2}}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}\textbf{#3}\hfill\textbf{#4}\\
  \addlinespace
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth] \addlinespace[1.4ex] 
}{%
  \\ \addlinespace
  \midrule \addlinespace
  \end{tabular}
  \par\vspace{1em}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{card}{NFR}{1}{Extensibility}{P1}
Description text.
\end{card}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The spacings seem not to obey any specific rule, though.

Note that the parameter for the intercolumn spaces is not `\columnsep`, but rather `\tabcolsep` (and each column has such space at either side).

[image]